# PHP header include page not displaying on all pages

Tags: php, html

Well I'm back with another problem, but hopefully I can get it solved before 11:00pm (pacific time).

So here are the basics.
1)  Folder structure is cas225/module7/pht/home, or image, or includes, or tours.
2)  My header.inc.html.php is located in the includes folder.
3)  Main page (home.html.php) is in the home folder, but the index.php calls it from the pht folder.
4)  tours folder has it's one index.php file in there.  But its main page, tours.html.php is located in this folder as well.

Now with that in place, my issue is with getting my header.inc.html.php to display on both the main page and the tours page.  Currently I can get this to display on my main page, but not the tours page.

This is the code I have in my header.

```html
<?php define('BASE_URL', '/cas225/module7/pht/'); ?>

<header>
  <img src="<?php echo 'images/portlandhistoricaltoursheader.png'; ?> " alt="Portland Historical Tours" width="920" height="290">
</header>
```

Here is the code for displaying this on my home page.  Please keep in mind that I also have a nav, and footer include page that work like the header, but they are working at the moment.

```html
CODE FOR HOME PAGE
<?php include 'includes/header.inc.html.php'; ?>

CODE FOR THE TOURS PAGE
<?php include '../includes/header.inc.html.php'; ?>
```

If it's needed, here is the code for the nav & footer.

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>tours">Tours</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>reservations">Reservations</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

-----------------

<footer> 
      <div class="footernav">
        <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>">Home</a>
        <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>tours">Tours</a>
        <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>reservations">Reservations</a>
        <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
        <p>Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y') ?> Portland Historical Tours<br>
        <a href="mailto:hello@portlandhistoricaltours.com">hello@portlandhistoricaltours.com</a></p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Have you tried a config file with an absolute path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how your file structure is set up.  Have you tried the following...

```
<header>
  <img src="/images/portlandhistoricaltoursheader.png" alt="Portland Historical Tours" width="920" height="290">
</header>
```

or

```
 <header>
      <img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; ?>/images/...">
</header>
```

The other thing to try, being that your pages are all over the place, is to try to use relative paths.  try adding `../../` or `../../../` before your image to see if you can locate where the image is on the server based on where your page is that is loading it.

Comment: I gave it a try, however the image won't display for either page when I do that.

The Home page is at: cas225/module7/pht/home/home.html.php
The Tours page is at:  cas225/module7/pht/tours/tours.html.php
The Header is at:  cas225/module7/pht/includes/header.inc.html.php

Comment: being that the file is located in different "relative" paths based on the same file being included in multiple pages, you're going to have to use absolute path.  Did you try the echoing the base_url before the image?  Or just the `../../`

Comment: I've got a solution for you...just trying to find the code.  I've used it successfully in the past on a big project

Comment: So adding echo $BASE_URL before the includes gives the following warning:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cas225\module7\pht\tours\tours.html.php on line 17. 
---------
And adding "../../" won't work either as it gives another set of errors. saying it failed to open/no such file or directory in:  cas225\module7\pht\tours\tours.html.php on line 17.

Comment: before I make a complex piece of code...have you tried adding a / before images?  This is called 'root relative'

Comment: Yes, adding that makes the image on the main page not be displayed.  But if I add ../ in front of images it will work for the tour page, but not for the main page.

Comment: check it using the ` $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` part in my new answer.  That honestly SHOULD work on all pages.

Comment: The only thing about this is that I have to have the: alt="Portland Historical Tours" width="920" height="290"> included into it.  Also the code doesn't seem to work as it gives me a broken image icon on both pages.

Comment: do <?php echo  $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; ?> and tell me what it says.  You can still have that in there....

Comment: its either `<img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; ?>"/images/portlandhistoricaltoursheader.png" alt="Portland Historical Tours" width="920" height="290">`   or `<img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; ?>"images/portlandhistoricaltoursheader.png" alt="Portland Historical Tours" width="920" height="290">`...cant remember if slash is included in server_name

Comment: hopefully this fixed the problem for you.  If so, can you accept as answer.

Comment: This, unfortunately doesn't solve the problem.  When I copy in the code, the </header> turns red.  I implemented it anyway to see what would happen.  The header image just wouldn't display.

Comment: Take out the “ after the ?> my apologies.